# Is there a way to set a default color for transparency when using ColorConvertOp in Java2D?

Tags: java, colors, java-2d, color-space

I'm converting an image with transparency in it into a Colorspace that doesn't have transparency.  I'd like to set a background color for the transparent areas.  Right now when I convert it any area that is transparent turns to black in the final image.  Is there a way to do that while I'm converting between ColorSpaces?  Here is my code I use to convert between color spaces:

```
public BufferedImage convertColorspace( BufferedImage source, int newType) {
    BufferedImage destination = new BufferedImage( source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), newType);
    ColorConvertOp colorConvertOp = new ColorConvertOp(null);
    colorConvertOp.filter(source, destination);
    return destination;
}

// here is how its used
BufferedImage converted = convertColorspace(combinedImage, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
```

I'm converting from BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ARGB to BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
    BufferedImage temp = new BufferedImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), 
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = temp.createGraphics();
    g2.setColor(Color.green);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
    g2.drawImage(0, 0, source, null);
    g2.dispose();
```

Then call `colorConvertOp.filter` with `temp` instead of `source`.